# Start activity from `onTick()` of `CoundownTimer`

Tags: android, countdowntimer, start-activity

I am trying to start activity from `onTick()` of `CountDownTimer`. It crashes my app. It is giving me this error `OutOfResourcesException initializing HW surface android.view.Surface$OutOfResourcesException: eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC` and Here is my logcat

```
    12-06 13:05:37.519: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): SwapBuffers() dequeue native buffer fail: Out of memory
12-06 13:05:37.519: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): GetSurfaceSize() dequeue native buffer failed: Out of memory.
12-06 13:05:37.519: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): GetSurfaceSize() dequeue native buffer failed: Device or resource busy.
12-06 13:05:37.519: E/Adreno200-EGL(5424): <eglSurfaceResize:4020>: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
12-06 13:05:37.589: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): GetSurfaceSize() dequeue native buffer failed: Out of memory.
12-06 13:05:37.589: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): GetSurfaceSize() dequeue native buffer failed: Out of memory.
12-06 13:05:37.589: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5424): GetSurfaceSize() dequeue native buffer failed: Out of memory.
12-06 13:05:37.589: E/Adreno200-EGL(5424): <qeglDrvAPI_eglMakeCurrent:2734>: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
12-06 13:05:37.589: E/libEGL(5424): eglMakeCurrent:678 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424): OutOfResourcesException initializing HW surface
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424): android.view.Surface$OutOfResourcesException: eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:689)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:519)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1300)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2445)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-06 13:05:37.599: E/ViewRootImpl(5424):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my `onTick()` function code.

```
private void updateContainerTextView() {
        updateContainerTextViewCounter = new CountDownTimer(
                totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {

                SingleTon.getInstance().playersGamerOver = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < SingleTon.getInstance().listOfPlayersInRoom
                        .size(); i++) {
                    if (!SingleTon.getInstance().listOfPlayersInRoom.get(i)
                            .isGameOver()) {                        
                        SingleTon.getInstance().playersGamerOver = false;                   
                    }
                }
                if (SingleTon.getInstance().playersGamerOver) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Players Game over",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateContainerTextViewCounter.cancel();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameOverScreen.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: How often does your timer tick? Maybe you're firing 1,000 activities to launch *per second* filling your ram really fast.

Comment: That's 20 activities a second if you don't kill the timer. Do you need 20 activities started per second?

Comment: The SingleTon use makes me cringe.

Comment: This is very bad way you are using to start an activity, instead you should start new activity only when timer is ticked for last time.

Comment: I have also tried this `if (SingleTon.getInstance().playersGamerOver) { updateContainerTextViewCounter.onFinish();}` and called startActivity in onFinish(); but result is same.